# Cannot find entry file index.js with Expo XDE

Tags: react-native, expo

When I load my react-native app in Expo I get the error: **"Cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots."**

I am adding onto an existing React Web App, and have index.ios.js at the root level. Everything works fine locally, in simulator and through Xcode on my phone hardwired. I've converted my app with `exp convert` and integrated all info into `exp.json`.

All info for the ios app is contained in a folder called "ios".

Has anyone run into this or have any thoughts on how to get unstuck?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

check you package.json and rename index.js to your entry file.

```
//...
},
  "main": "index.js"
}
```

Comment: Wish I had realized this before I upgraded to the latest Expo, now I have a different problem, it's hanging on `exp convert`. Thank you! Will try it out if I get this going again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Expo, you need to go to your project folder and find the below file:

*\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js*

```
import { KeepAwake, registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import App from '../../App';

if (__DEV__) {
  KeepAwake.activate();
}

registerRootComponent(App);
```

and here just replace the `App` to `Custom_Component_Name` in the second line of import.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the entry file by looking in the `package.json` file. In package.json you will find

```
{            
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js"
}
```

`AppEntry.json` is the entry file by default in expo projects.