# Cannot find entry file index.js

Tags: react-native

I tried to add push notifications to my app with https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm module.
I end up with lots of errors and run many react commands on node including uprade commands.
Now on simulator red screen says "Can not find entry file index.js in any of to roots" and when I look at the ReactPackager it says:

```
Loading dependency graph, done. Bundlingindex.js[development, non-minified] 0.0% (0/1), failed. error: bundling failed: Error at DependencyGraph._getAbsolutePath (/Users/beratuslu/Desktop/react-native-starter-app/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:305:11) at DependencyGraph.getDependencies (/Users/beratuslu/Desktop/react-native-starter-app/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:283:4236) at Resolver.getDependencies (/Users/beratuslu/Desktop/react-native-starter-app/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/Resolver/index.js:129:5) at /Users/beratuslu/Desktop/react-native-starter-app/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/Bundler/index.js:642:39 at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at step (/Users/beratuslu/Desktop/react-native-starter-app/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/Bundler/index.js:13:1336) at /Users/beratuslu/Desktop/react-native-starter-app/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/Bundler/index.js:13:1496 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

[image]

Here is my package.json: https://pastebin.com/2CsXCyJt

Any help appreciated...

Comment: can you provide your package.json please

Comment: I added my package.json

Comment: try upgrading `"babel-preset-react-native": "3.0.1",` and make sure your .babelrc contains` "presets": ["react-native"]`
I faced such issue it had to do with something relate to babel libraries in my dev dependencies so i deleted babel related libraries and kept only babel-preset-react-native and babel-jest

Comment: Guys check the mentioned link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50676695/4655652)

Answer (score 10):

From react native 0.49.1 there is a breaking change, Merge your index.android.js and index.ios.js into index.js.
For more details see this issue in [Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16208)

Answer (score 0):

You can just try the following steps

1. `(in project directory) mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`
2. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
3. `react-native run-android`